# Deviating from standard Danish gambit

Tags: opening, strategy, gambits, minor-variations

I like to play the Danish gambit opening. Frequently, black won't take the last pawn to complete the standard opening, but instead plays the knight as shown below. I'll generally play Queen to `b3` or `f3`. But then black plays Knight to `a5` or `e5`, respectively, which results in losing the `c4` bishop. Is there a nice way for white to respond to `Nc6`?

```
[fen "r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/8/2B1P3/2p5/PP3PPP/RNBQK1NR w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Note that after 5.Qb3, 3...Na5 is not a good move, because after 6.Bxf7+ Ke7 7.Qxc3 Kxf7 8.Qxa5 material is equal and Black's king is very exposed.

Answer (score 3):

Just develop your pieces. `5.Nf3` makes sense, preparing to castle. `5.Nxc3` is also reasonable; if Black refuses to play `... cxb2`, you'll probably have to play `Nxc3` at some point anyway. These are the only two [regularly played moves](http://www.365chess.com/opening.php?m=9&n=3595&ms=e4.e5.d4.exd4.c3.dxc3.Bc4.Nc6&ns=3.5.74.130.434.503.435.3595) in the given position.